# Write an Erlang function called sort_of_sum that takes one argument List. The function should behave as follows:

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

Write an Erlang function called sort_of_sum that takes one argument List. The function should behave as follows:

(Use pattern matching to solve this question.)

- If List is a list with no elements, print “There is nothing there!”
- If List is a list with one element, print “The sum is sum.” where sum is the element.
- If List is a list with two elements, print “The sum is sum.” where sum is the sum of the two elements.
- If List is a list with three elements, print “The sum is sum.” where sum is the sum of the three elements.
- If List is a list with more than three elements, print “That’s too many to add!” Hint: You will probably need to make use of the tail construct | somehow to pattern match this.
- If List is anything else, print “I can’t add that!”

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: -module(main).
-export([sort_of_sum/1]).

sort_of_sum(List=[]) ->
 io:format('There is nothing there! ~s~n',[List]);
sort_of_sum([H|_]) ->
 sum = H ,
 io:format('The sum is ~s~n',[sum]).

Comment: Don't paste code to a comment. Update your question, please.

Comment: I am also new to Erlang so I was trying to do it in pieces

Comment: Pattern matching is exactly "doing it in pieces".

Comment: Use the `~w` format, not `~s` for the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `~w` to format the integers, not `~s`. You were on the right track.

```erlang
-module(main).
-export([sort_of_sum/1]).

sort_of_sum([]) ->
    io:format("There is nothing there!~n");
sort_of_sum([H]) ->
    io:format("The sum is ~w.~n", [H]);
sort_of_sum([H1, H2]) ->
    io:format("The sum is ~w.~n", [H1 + H2]);
sort_of_sum([H1, H2, H3]) ->
    io:format("The sum is ~w.~n", [H1 + H2 + H3]);
sort_of_sum([_H | _T]) ->
    io:format("That's too many to add!~n");
sort_of_sum(_) ->
    io:format("I can't add that!~n").
```